# Restricted Maximum Likelihood Estimates of Multilevel Regression Model

Tags: self-study, maximum-likelihood, references, multilevel-analysis, reml

A two-level regression model :

$$Y_{ij} = \gamma_{00} + \gamma_{10}X_{ij} + \gamma_{01}Z_j + \gamma_{11}X_{ij}Z_j + u_{0j} + u_{1j}X_{ij} + e_{ij}$$

where $e_{ij}\sim N(0,\sigma^2_e)$ and , 
$$
 \begin{bmatrix}
 u_{0j} \\
 u_{1j} \\
 \end{bmatrix}\sim N \begin{pmatrix}
 \begin{bmatrix}
 0 \\
 0 \\
 \end{bmatrix}, \begin{bmatrix}
 \sigma^2_{u0}&0 \\
 0&\sigma^2_{u1}\\
 \end{bmatrix}
 \end{pmatrix}
 $$

Can anyone please give reference or explain in detail  how is to derive the restricted maximum likelihood estimates of fixed effect parameters $(\gamma_{00},\gamma_{10},\gamma_{01},\gamma_{11})$ and random effect parameters  $(\sigma^2_{u0},\sigma^2_{u1})$  ?

In [this book, section 2.4.2](http://books.google.be/books?id=467ym_ivHMUC&printsec=frontcover&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false) described restricted maximum likelihood estimation procedure for simpler model than the two-level regression model.

Comment: G.M. Fitzmaurice, N.M. Laird, J.H. Waird, "Applied longitudinal analysis" has a section on REML.

Comment: Another reference is this one (page 75 and next): http://verde.esalq.usp.br/~jorge/cursos/modelos_longitudinais/Mixed%20Effects%20Models%20in%20S%20and%20S-Plus.pdf